# How to kill child_process properly ?

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, fedora, atom-editor

In atom-text-editor plugin development, I run a child_process like,

```
cp = require 'child_process'
command = "python /home/user45/jedi-python2-complete.py"
@jediServer = cp.exec command
```

And i kill the process like this,

```
process.kill(@jediServer.pid)
```

In ubuntu-os two process are created as sh and python(jedi-python2-complete.py) but in fedora only one process is created (jedi-python2-complete.py).

When i attempt to kill the process in ubuntu using process.kill only sh-process was killed but the python process stays running in the background.., while in fedora the python process is getting killed.

For example, 
in ubuntu,
 sh pid-3560
 python pid-3561

in fedora the python-process pid- 3560

I relatively tried solving it like,

```
process.kill(pid)
process.kill(pid+1)
```

But is there any other way., common to linux os.

Comment: [try this](http://azimi.me/2014/12/31/kill-child_process-node-js.html)

Answer (score 1):

You better to use Atom's wrapper around child_process called [BufferedProcess](https://atom.io/docs/api/latest/BufferedProcess). It will kill process properly on Windows if you will use their own .kill method.

You may take a look on how to use it in this [autocomplete-python](https://github.com/sadovnychyi/autocomplete-python/blob/master/lib/provider.coffee#L43) package sources.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me ,

```
cp = require 'child_process'
command = "python"
env = process.env
spawn = cp.spawn
@jediServer = spawn(command,[__dirname + jedi-python2-complete.py],env:env)
```

And i killed the process like this,

```
@jediServer.kill()
```

This worked the same in both ubuntu, fedora with no variations. 
Referred code from user [Michael Aquilina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507706/michael-aquilina)